# Siebel read only field problem

Tags: components, siebel

I'm trying to make a field read only when a given value is selected from a PickList.
I'm using a flag that is set to Y when the list has that value, and N otherwise.

I created a Business Component User Prop with the name Field Read Only Field: MyField set to the flag.

Thing is, this works with the vanilla component but it wont work on my custom component.
I can't figure out what is going on, the properties of the fields and flag are exactly the same. It should work...

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

That user property is only supported on the business component class CSSBCBase and its subclasses.  My guess is that you probably used CSSBusComp as the class of your business component.  CSSBusComp is actually a superclass of CSSBCBase, and is very minimal and does not support Field Read Only Field.  If that's the case, change it to CSSBCBase and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is that- if the record become read-only when the picklist value is being selected- that you'll need to make the picklist field Immediate Post Changes to be sure the user property is triggered.